# Clear contents and fill with new value up to last row, but how to keep LastRow?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about saving the rownumber and then filling data with it in the next for loop like below. However, when I run this, it runs the code to find the LastRow again which then does not exist anymore as it's empty.

```
Sub kolomE()

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
     LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    
End With

Range("E3:E3" & LastRow).ClearContents
Range("E3:E3" & LastRow) = "&omegaOne="

End Sub
```

So I want it to fill the cells it cleared with .ClearContents to fill it with "&omegaOne="

Comment: do you mean you want to keep `LastRow` for next time you run this code ? or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to erase row number from your ranges. It should be:

```
Range("E3:E" & LastRow).ClearContents
Range("E3:E" & LastRow).Value = "&omegaOne="
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I didn't know that would cause the issue.. :/